# Every ideal in ring of integers contains a natural number

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $O$ be the ring of integers of some number field and $I$ any nonzero ideal of $O$. Prove that there is some number $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$  that is in ideal $I$.

I suppose I should use that $O$ is Dedekind domain, so every ideal can be written as product of prime ideals, but I don't know how to use that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3595169/631274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb K$ be a number field of degree $n$ and $O$ the ring of integers in $K$. Let $I$ be an ideal in $O$ and $x\in I$. Note that all $n$ conjugates $x=x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ of $x$ are also algebraic integers, since they have the same minimum polynomial. Therefore, their product $x.x_2 ... x_n$ is an algebraic integer,  and belongs to the ideal $I$. Finally, note that  the product $x.x_2 ... x_n$  equals the norm $N(x)$,  so it is a positive rational integer.

Comment: Note that $x_2, \cdots, x_n$ do not need to be elements of $O$, or even $K$, so *a priori* it's not obvious that their product is an element of $I$. However, you can use the minimum polynomial to show $N(x)$ is a multiple of $x$.

Comment: This really helps me.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Show that $O/I$ is finite for any nonzero ideal $I.$